# What is the difference between bpy.types.IntProperty and bpy.props.IntProperty?

Tags: python, properties

I am always confused between `bpy.types.IntProperty` and `bpy.props.IntProperty`. (similarly with other properties)

Most of the examples do use `bpy.props.IntProperty`, but I never came across a clear explanation of the difference between them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`bpy.types.IntProperty` is a *type*, used for the property descriptions in the RNA system for any int property. E.g. you get

```
>>> type(bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].bl_rna.properties['frame_start'])
<class 'bpy.types.IntProperty'>
```

Note that i did not actually use `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_start`. That would actually evaluate the property and return a standard python int value, not the property definition.

`bpy.props.IntProperty` on the other hand is a *function* which creates such a property definition (a constructor).

Technically it's slightly more complicated because in order to create the property as part of a class the function returns a temporary tuple of another function and the arguments you passed. This is then used by a metaclass to create the actual `IntProperty` and put it inside the class definition.

```
>>> bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Hello")
(<built-in function IntProperty>, {'name': 'Hello'})
```

Comment: +1 Consice and in-depth technical explanation. I was looking for such an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I have been reading about the python data model and metaclass infrastructure in Python (bpy_types.py). So if i understand correctly, the metaclasses are creating actual python properties (getters, setters) and storing type info in bl_rna (behind the scenes)!

Comment: @satishgoda, mostly right - but this is really internal details we don't expect many devs to need to know. The metaclasses don't create getters/setters, instead they modify the RNA definitions (internal blender/c data), that in-turn will be exposed though the existing getattr/setattr's which are generic for all RNA, this is how the values can be animated or display in the interface (which don't have to go through python at all).

Comment: @ideasman42 Thank you for clarifying. Its really helps as I am making my way through the sources. :)

Answer (score 2):

`*Property` functions in [`bpy.props`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.props.html) module are what we use to instantiate the property. Classes with the same name in [`bpy.types`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.html) contains structure related to the property, accessible at runtime.

For example, in the snippet below I use [`bpy.props.IntProperty`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.IntProperty) function to add a custom property to a scene object. Even though `scene.int_prop` is a Python integer, I can still access the property's structure as `scene.rna_type.properties['int_prop']`, and the type will be [`bpy.types.IntProperty`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.IntProperty.html):

```
import bpy

bpy.types.Scene.int_prop = bpy.props.IntProperty(default=9)

# > 9
print(bpy.context.scene.int_prop)

# > <class 'int'>
print(type(bpy.context.scene.int_prop))

# > <class 'bpy.types.IntProperty'>
print(type(bpy.context.scene.rna_type.properties['int_prop']))

del bpy.types.Scene.int_prop
```